# Resharper C++ and Plog logger

Tags: c++, this, resharper

I am using Plog in my project for logging.  I also use resharper c++.

There are several macros used for logging that make it less verbose.  One of the macros always gets marked as an issue with Resharper but I don't know why.

The macro is LOGD which expands to

```
            if (!plog::get<0>() || !plog::get<0>()- 
              >checkSeverity(plog::debug)) {;} else (*plog::get<0>()) += 
              plog::Record(plog::debug, __FUNCTION__, 151, "", 
              __if_exists(this) { this } __if_not_exists(this) { 0 }) << 
              "Message";
```

The warning points to the usage of "this" as it expects an identifier.

The method it is calling has a signature of:

```
Record(Severity severity, const char* func, size_t line, const char* file, const void* object)
        : m_severity(severity), m_tid(util::gettid()), m_object(object), m_line(line), m_func(func), m_file(file)
```

Does anyone have experience with this an know how to modify the macro so it does not complain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've filed [RSCPP-22423](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-22423), we'll try to fix this in one of the 2018.2 EAP builds. Until then, you can redefine the `PLOG_GET_THIS` macro for ReSharper C++ like this:

```
#include <plog/Log.h>
#if defined(__RESHARPER__)
#define PLOG_GET_THIS() reinterpret_cast<void*>(0)
#endif
```

Or similarly update the original definition of `PLOG_GET_THIS` (it already checks for the similar `__INTELLISENSE__` macro to determine if `__if_exists` can be used).

Comment: Checking for `__RESHARPER__` has been added to plog. Just get the latest version of it.